# Jquery .css scale image from current size

Tags: jquery, css, image, scale

I'm trying to resize images from current size, not from original size, because I have made different transform attributes to images (in css file) when the screen size changes (with @media screen.. {} so it would look the same in different size of screens).

```
//..this is only part of a code of a jslider..

callback: function( value ){
    var SliderValue = $('#SliderSingle2').attr('value');
    if(value== "2003"){                         
        //intresting part here:
        var currentSize = $("#img").css('transform');
        var currentSize = parseFloat(currentSize)*1.2;
        $("#img").css('transform', currentSize);
        alert(currentSize);
    }
}

//...that alert returns now NaN so parseFloat can't read 
//transform:scale(0.6) attribute.. but there isn't parseDouble option.. 
//Any succestions??
```

What I'm trying to do is this: ([link](http://www.technicalkeeda.com/demo/how-to-increase-decrease-font-size-of-page-using-jquery)) only with the images, not fonts..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're getting the NaN value in the alert is because:

```
var currentSize = $('#img').css('transform'); //Returns a string. Example: "matrix(a,b,c,d,tx,ty)"
parseFloat(currentSize); // NaN
```

More on that here: [CSS Transform on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform)

You'll need to do the math required to convert the returned matrix into a usable value. Then feed the adjusted value back into the jQuery CSS method. Another option is to maybe try something like this:

```
var imgWidth = Math.round($('#img').css('width').replace('px','')*1.2),
    imgHeight = Math.round($('#img').css('height').replace('px','')*1.2);

$('#img').css({ width:imgWidth, height:imgHeight });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I used Math.round in the example above, but you might want to consider using either Math.floor() or Math.ceil() to handle rounding.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using background-size:cover? You would then change the container size and the image size would follow it.

```
<div style="background-image:url('myImage.jpg'); background-size:cover;"></div>
```

Comment: I considered that too, because jquery has got this imagescale plugin as well (to cover div #container).. Do you mean resize div like this: var resizedHeight = $("div#container").css("height","30%");$("div#container").css("widht","30%");..or those pixels?.. It is a little bit difficult to understand how to make that container responsive to screen sizes..

Comment: or something around like width: 300px; height: auto ?

Comment: I haven't seen your HTML code, but assigning a percentage value to the width and height of the div would make it responsive